# How to prevent cheating on sending data(location, latitude & longitude) from client side to server side?

Tags: javascript, php, html, http, geolocation

I use PHP for developing web application. I need user location, latitude and longitude. Latitude and longitude are sensitive and I need actual lat&lng.

HTML5 geo location API will return lat&lng, but users can edit their java scripts on client side or they can send fake lat&lng to server side.

Is there a solution to get actual user lat&lng?
How can I prevent cheating? 
Can I use http only cookies or something else?

Comment: 3x No. You cannot prevent the spoofing of anything that is sent by the client.

Comment: You cannot and you should not force your users to something. If someone decides to send custom made data, then it is his good right to do so. Only he will be able to tell why, that is none of your business in the end.

Comment: @arkascha I will say an example: Our app will get user location and we offer them a discount depend on their location. How can i prevent cheating? Can i use something else like token or ...?

Comment: @VahidMontazer: You can't.  The user can send to the server whatever data they want to send.  They can send a correct location, they can send an incorrect location, they can send no location at all, they can send a recipe for biscuits, they can send whatever they like.  It's a numbers game.  Most users won't bother.  A small number of users will game the system.  If the business is completely hosed by this small number of outliers, then the business is relying on the wrong things.

Comment: You can't. You simply cannot rely on any data you are given from the client side. That is outside your control, whatever you try. All you can do is go to the specified location and check if the person actually is there and is who she claims she is.

Comment: @VahidMontazer: `"we offer them a discount depend on their location"` - And when the shipping and/or billing address is in a different location, you'll know something is wrong.

Comment: OK! But I think in this case many of developers are limit and they can't develop good applications for better life. Perhaps in next days we can get actual user location if they allow or anything if they don't allow. I need just this now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent cheating. Treat every data coming from user-land as untrusted.

HTTP only cookies can be altered with proxy-software such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

You can use an IP address to lat/lon database, which might help you identify fraudulent responses, but even an IP address can be spoofed, or the user can be using a VPN service located on another continent.

Comment: I would also like to note that sometimes the IP-lookup databases are wrong as well. Quite a few times I've been told that I live in the Netherlands, which is about 2000 km away (or just under four and a half hours by plane).